# Graph with girth 5 and exactly $k^2+1$ vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm doing a homework and I've already done the proof that a graph with girth 5 and degree of atleast $k$ has at least $k^2+1$ vertices.

Also I've been able to found a graph for $k=2$ and $k=3$ but searching over the web I've found it's impossible to found one with $k=4$. How can I prove that it's impossible to find one?

Comment: What is the degree of a graph?

Comment: Do you mean $k-$regular, instead of just degree which applies to an individual vertex?

Comment: You are potentially referring to the Hoffman-Singleton theorem, which states that for $k-$regular graph, we can only have $k=2, 3, 7, 57$. If so, you can see [here - qn 2](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/PSet6.pdf) for an approach.

Comment: Yes, I mean a k-regular graph. Looks a little bit more advanced than I though so I will answer as it's just impossible

Comment: How you did the proof that a graph with girth 5 and degree of atleast k has at least k2+1 vertices??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two graphs that work are the Hoffman-Singleton graph (degree 7) and the Petersen graph (degree 3).

For degree 4, you'd need a girth 5 graph with 17 vertices.  The fewest possible vertices is a cage graph, the [Robertson graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RobertsonGraph.html), with 19 vertices.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the robertson graph as to show that it's the graph with the fewest possible vertices.